# Hard Drive Selection for NAS enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I just picked up a two drive NAS enclosure (Dlink DNS-323) and am looking for some suggestions for hard drives to install into it.

Is a "green" drive sufficient or will there be a performance hit?
32 or 64 mb buffer?

Comment: More buffer is better, rotational speed should be not be a problem since it will still be more than sufficient to keep up with network transfer speeds, Unless you are going to multitask it on a gigabit network. Really depends on what your planned purpose for the NAS is and how large the network is and how many will be accessing the NAS at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

In general it depends a lot on what you're planning to do with your NAS, but given your choice of NAS, I don't think the drives will ever be the bottleneck, so you can buy pretty much what you like the most.

It's also worth pointing out that many "Green Drives" are not intended for 24/7 usage anyway.

If you get one of the most recent WD Caviar Green Power, you should be aware that they come set up with aggressive power management, so they tend to unload and load their heads quite frequently.

This might lead to premature failing. Several NAS manufacturers (e.g. [Synology](http://www.synology.com/support/faq_show.php?q_id=407)) are advising their customers to switch off this feature. For this you need a [proprietary tool](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=609&sid=113) which only runs under DOS.

Comment: @ pico, "This utility is designed to upgrade the firmware of the following hard drives: WD1000FYPS-01ZKB0, WD7500AYPS-01ZKB0, WD7501AYPS-01ZKB0."

Comment: I know, that's one of the many hidiosincrasies of WDC. There's no utility targeted specifically at Caviar Green models, so that's the only choice at the moment. It works (tested personally). From a technical standpoint there should be no need for a proprietary utility since there are standard commands to set APM, but WDC chose to implement their own. Go figure.

Comment: So this utility works on other WD drive models? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but not all of them. It will work with models it's not needed for, and there are anecdotal reports of it not working on drives it is supposed to. BTW to the best of my knowledge, it does NOT upgrade the firmware, its only sends commands to alter the idle timeout after which the heads are unloaded.

Comment: But aren't those commands part of the firmware?

Comment: AFAIK it just "tells" the drive to set the time out to n seconds, the same way it would issue a standard command to enter sleep or standby. That isn't upgrading the firmware, as much as issuing a `dir` command in a cmd.exe shell doesn't mean you're upgrading Windows. However I didn't reverse engineer WDIDLE3 so this is just my understanding of the matter.

Comment: I assumed that command was stored in the firmware, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for years on Hitachi Deskstar disk drives with no flaw.

The only one that failed has run for 6 years 24/7... I consider this a nice MTBF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTBF)